# How do I create a View to use Bootstrap Paragraph fields and group by the title?

Tags: views, search, paragraphs

I have a View for FAQ's, and an exposed combined fields filter. I created an FAQ content type, and added a paragraph field that contains "Question" and "Answer" fields. I cant use Search API, and want to find a way for this to work with Views.

If I choose to make a page of fields, the paragraph fields don't work in the combined field search.

If I choose to do a page of paragraph fields, I cant add the title field.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Has anyone else ran into this? I'm sure I can do it with Search API, but then I'd have to recreate 4 other search areas.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to combine paragraph and regular fields in a view.